# Use console output of command-line tool in Powershell pipeline

Tags: powershell, command-line, pipeline

In my PowerShell script, I'd like to use the output of a tool like **git**.

For example, the command line

```
git status
```

returns

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Now I tried to use this output in the following pipeline command:

```
git status | $_.Contains("nothing to commit")
```

But I get the error

`Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$msg = [string](git status) | where { $_.Contains("nothing to commit") }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select-string`:

```
git status | select-string "nothing to commit"
```